# Browser Sync multiple reloads

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, browser-sync, slim-lang

I'm new to **Gulp.js** and I'm trying to create a template for static websites using slim/coffee/sass and **Browser Sync**.

I have an issue with my **slim task** (*compile slim to html*): when I edit a slim file gulp run the slim task a lot of times depending on the number of slim files in the project. (*so if I have 5 slim files and I edit the title of one of them, gulp will run the slim task 5 times.*)

The problem is that in this task I ask Browser Sync to reload the server whenever I edit a slim file. *Using again the exemple above, if I edit a title in one file, the server will reload 5 times*. And this is realy annoying.

I hope someone got a solution for this issue :)

**Here the slim task in my gulpfile:**

```
gulp.task('slim', function () {
 return gulp.src(slim_dev + '/**/*.slim')
  // prevent server from crashing
  .pipe(plugins.plumber({ errorHandler: function(err) {
    plugins.notify.onError({
      title: "Gulp error in " + err.plugin
    })(err);
  }}))
  // compile slim to html
  .pipe(plugins.slim({
    pretty: false,
    include: true
  }))
  // minify html
  .pipe(plugins.minifyHtml())
  // copy result to build folder
  .pipe(gulp.dest(slim_build))
  // reload server on slim save
  .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
  // notify when task completed
  .pipe(plugins.notify('Slim compilation completed !'));
});
```

**Here the global gulpfile:**

```
// GULP TEMPLATE - Gulfile.js - Victor Allegret
//
//   - $ gulp
//   - $ gulp build
//   - $ gulp clean
//
// --------------------------------------------------------

////////////////////
// VARIABLES
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// REQUIRE
// ---------------------------------------------------------

var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
        pattern: '*'
    }),
    reload  = plugins.browserSync.reload


// PATH
// ---------------------------------------------------------

///// PATHS FOR DEV
var slim_dev    = './dev/views/',
    sass_dev    = './dev/assets/stylesheets/',
    coffee_dev  = './dev/assets/javascripts/',
    fonts_dev   = './dev/assets/fonts/',
    img_dev     = './dev/assets/images/',
    dev         = './dev';

///// PATH FOR PROD
var slim_build     = './build/views/',
    sass_build     = './build/assets/stylesheets/',
    coffee_build   = './build/assets/javascripts/',
    fonts_build    = './build/assets/fonts/',
    img_build      = './build/assets/images/',
    build          = './build';





////////////////////
// TASKS
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// COMPILE SLIM TO HTML
// ---------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('slim', function () {
  return gulp.src(slim_dev + '/**/*.slim')
    // prevent server from crashing
    .pipe(plugins.plumber({ errorHandler: function(err) {
      plugins.notify.onError({
          title: "Gulp error in " + err.plugin
      })(err);
    }}))
    // compile slim to html
    .pipe(plugins.slim({
      pretty: false,
      include: true
    }))
    // minify html
    .pipe(plugins.minifyHtml())
    // copy result to build folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest(slim_build))
    // reload server on slim save
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
    // notify when task completed
    .pipe(plugins.notify('Slim compilation completed !'));
});


// COMPILE SASS TO CSS
// ---------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(sass_dev + '/**/*.{sass,css,scss}')
    // prevent server from crashing
    .pipe(plugins.plumber({ errorHandler: function(err) {
      plugins.notify.onError({
          title: "Gulp error in " + err.plugin,
      })(err);
    }}))
    // compile sass to css
    .pipe(plugins.sass())
    // add auto-prefixes
    .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
      cascade: false
    }))
    // concat all files
    .pipe(plugins.concat('main.css'))
    // rename to .min
    .pipe(plugins.rename('main.min.css'))
    // minify css
    .pipe(plugins.minifyCss())
    // copy result to build folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest(sass_build))
    // reload on sass save
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
    // notify when task completed
    .pipe(plugins.notify('Sass compilation completed !'));
});


// COMPILE COFFEE TO JS
// ---------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('coffee', function() {
  return gulp.src(coffee_dev + '/**/*.coffee')
    // compile coffee to js
    .pipe(plugins.coffee())
    // concat all files
    .pipe(plugins.concat('all.js'))
    // rename to .min
    .pipe(plugins.rename('all.min.js'))
    // minify js
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    // copy result to build folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest(coffee_build))
    // notify when task completed
    .pipe(plugins.notify('Coffee compilation completed !'));
});


// FONTS
// ---------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src(fonts_dev + '/**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff}')
    // copy result to build folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest(fonts_build))
});


// REMOVE UNUSED CSS
// ---------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('uncss', function () {
  return gulp.src(sass_build + '/app.css')
  // remove unused css
   .pipe(plugins.uncss({
      html: [build + '/**/*.html']
   }))
   // minify css
   .pipe(plugins.minifyCss())
   // copy result to build folder
   .pipe(gulp.dest(sass_build))
   // notify when task completed
   .pipe(plugins.notify('Unused CSS removed !'));
});


// MINIFY IMAGES
// ---------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('img', function () {
  return gulp.src(img_dev + '/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}')
    // minify images
    .pipe(plugins.imagemin())
    // copy result to build folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest(img_build))
    // notify when task completed
    .pipe(plugins.notify('Images are optimized!'));
});


// REMOVE BUILD FOLDER
// ---------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('removeBuild', function () {
  return gulp.src(build, { read: false})
    .pipe(plugins.rimraf())
    .pipe(plugins.notify('Prod folder deleted !'));
});





////////////////////
// COMMANDS
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// RUN SLIM | SASS | COFFEE ($ gulp dev)
// ---------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('dev', ['slim', 'sass', 'coffee', 'fonts']);


// RUN SLIM | SASS | COFFEE | UNCSS | IMG ($ gulp build)
// ---------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('build', ['slim', 'sass', 'coffee', 'fonts', 'uncss', 'img']);


// RUN CLEAN ($ gulp clean)
// ---------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('clean', ['removeBuild']);


// RUN SERVER ($ gulp)
// ---------------------------------------------------------

///// WATCH
gulp.task('watch', ['dev'], function () {
  plugins.browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: slim_build,
      index: "index.html"
    },
    scrollProportionally: true,
    notify: false
  })
  gulp.watch(dev + '/**/*.slim', ['slim']);
  gulp.watch(dev + '/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(dev + '/**/*.coffee', ['coffee']);
  gulp.watch(build  + '/**/*.html').on('change', reload);
});

////// COMMAND
gulp.task('default', ['watch'])
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [browserSync stream option : once](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/api#api-stream).  So change this:

```
.pipe(reload({stream:true}))  // in 'slim' task
```

to

```
stream = plugins.browserSync.stream   //  for the "slim' task

.pipe(stream({once:true}))  // in 'slim' task
```

That option is supposed to reload browserSync only once per stream.

Comment: This addresses the reload multiple times problem.  I don't know slim and whether you need or want to run the 'slim' task for each slim file when one is edited.  If that is unnecessary, there are ways to deal with that, such as gulp-newer or gulp-changed, etc.

Comment: Your solution seems to work, thanks ! :) That fix the reload problem. Also gulp-newer looks realy useful for my template
Thank you